# Each object of a class has its own copy of each non-static member variable

Tags: java, object, variables, static, instance

I´m studying to get the JAVA SE8 certification, and I have a doubt with a question that I have found. My doubt is:

Does a instance of a class have its own copy of each member variable, if this member variable is non-static?

My answer to that question is yes, but the correction of the simulator that I´m using to study says that a object doesn´t have its own copy of the non-static member variable!

I don´t understand why, thanks for your help.

Comment: You are right and it is wrong, or you have misunderstood it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is - the instances of the class will have its own distinct copy of its non-static member variable. When we define the member variable as static, it will be assigned class lifetime, rather than instance lifetime.

Example:

```
Class A{
 String s;
 static String str;
}
```

Here you can access variable "s" using

```
new A().s;
```

Where as "str" using

```
A.str;
```